# VBA to ignore cell formating when adding a specific number using a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm that it's purpose is to generate numbers (2 digits ONLY).

I formatted the column 'C' in Excel to add a 0 at the end of any single number generated.

So, if my number generated is '5', I will see '50'.

**Now, for the problem,** If my number is 6, I don't want excel to add a 0 (60).

It's literally only for the number 6.

Is there a way to code this with VBA?

EDIT :

```
If TextBox4.Value = True Then

    message = MsgBox("Generate this number ? " & TextBox1 & TextBox2 & "." & TextBox3, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Number Generator")

    If message = vbYes Then

        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B4").Select
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B4:F4").Select
        Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B4").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = UCase(TextBox2)

        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A4").Select
        Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
        ActiveCell.Value = UCase(TextBox1)

        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C4").Select
        Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
        ActiveCell.Value = "." & TextBox3

        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("G4").Select
        Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
        ActiveCell.Value = "RÉVISION"


        Sheets("Sheet3").Range("H4").Select
        Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
        ActiveCell.Value = TextBox4.Value

        MsgBox ("The Number is : " & Sheet4.Cells(4, "A").Value & Format$(Sheet4.Cells(4, "B").Value, "0000#") & "." & Sheet4.Cells(4, "C"))

    End If


Else
    Exit Sub
End If


End If
End If
```

Comment: How dit you format that column to ad a 0 at the end of the number? Usually, formatting does not change the number value, only the way you see it... Did you do that using ##"0" Custom format?

Comment: Selected entire column, clicked 'Format Cells..' , 'Custom', and in Type : ''.00''. I dont want to change the Value of the number, it's really just for the way I see it ! @FaneDuru

Comment: `If myVal = 6 Then ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "General"`. Where `myVal` is the number to be written in a cell...

Comment: @FaneDuru didnt worked! I copied that line in my Worksheet (Sheet3). Or should I create a module?!

Comment: Do you understand what you are trying to do? You said "I have a UserForm that generate numbers." **Doesn't that form code triy to write in the specific range**? The code I supplied is an example regarding the way you must use in your (form) code. Meaning to programmatically change the specific cell in "General"... Please post your piece of code writing those numbers in C:C column and I will show you how to use it.

Comment: @FaneDuru I pasted the piece of code that generate the number

Comment: Firstly, no need to select anything! It  is better to use `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C4").Value = "." & TextBox3`. The single piece of code writing in column C:C looks to be the above one. The 6 number, I suppose to be in TextBox3. Is it correct? If yes, you can se mai previous example like this: But it is not place here put the code and you to understand something. I will try an answer instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a single piece of code writing in column C:C, adapt it in the next way:

Instead of:

```
 Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C4").Select
 Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
 ActiveCell.Value = "." & TextBox3
```

Try this, please:

```
If TextBox3.Text = "6" then
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C4").NumberFormat = "@"
end if
With Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C4")
   .Borders.Weight = xlThin
   .Value = "." & TextBox3.Text
End With
```

Comment: Works perfectly!! But only one tiny problem I havent mentionned. I will accept your answer btw. I just have a simple sub-question. In the textbox, let's say I put ''6''. On the sheet I will see ''.6''. This is what I want. The problem is, if I dont use a format, on the excel sheet, I will see ''0.6''.... I know it's completely unrelated but I need to be able to see ''.6''. Sorry If I didnt said this earlier.

Comment: @Codingnoob: I adapted the code to do what you say it would be better. The cell format must be text ("@")...