# Replace textbox input by a specific number

Tags: excel, vba

In my userform, users can enter numbers in a textbox (2 maximum).

The number then gets copied in a worksheet.

I'm trying to have any number entered in this textbox to get copied but with the number 6 at the end.

If the user enter '.14'; then in the worksheet, I need to see '.16'.
If the user enter '.45'; then in the worksheet, I need to see '.46'. 
And so on..

The only ***exception***, is If the user enter '6' in the textbox, then in the worksheet, I need to ONLY see '.6', and not '.66'. (this problem was fixed thanks to an answer received earlier : [VBA to ignore cell formating when adding a specific number using a userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60027718/vba-to-ignore-cell-formating-when-adding-a-specific-number-using-a-userform/60029601?noredirect=1#comment106165492_60029601))

I've used cell formating and entered ''.06'' In 'Type'. I thought It worked, but then when I enter let's say '.43' in the userform, the number that gets copied in the cell is not '.46' like expected, but ''.56''.

I dont know why.

EDIT :

I tried this but it's not working :

```
Sub ReplaceLastDigit()
    Dim r As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each r In Range("C4", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If IsNumeric(r) And Len(r) > 1 Then
            r = Left(r, Len(r) - 1) & "6"
        End If
    Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

EDIT 2:

Everything works, except one thing. When it's only ".6", it doesn't add ".66" (great), but it adds a zero. So I see ".60". Is it the formating?

This is the code :

```
If Left(TextBox3.Text, 1) <> 6 Then
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C4").Select
    Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
    ActiveCell.Value = "." & Left(TextBox3.Text, 1) & 6
Else
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C4").Select
    Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
    ActiveCell.Value = ".6"
End If
```

Comment: Here is one way: **[1.]** Allow only numeric numbers in the textbox. Not even decimals. We will add decimal before writing to the worksheet. **[2.]** Set the maxlength of the textbox to 2 in design time so that no one can enter more than 2 numbers **[3.]** Now simply use `Left(textBox1.text,1)` to get the left most number and then use `"." & Left(textBox1.text,1) & 6` to write to the worksheet

Comment: `The only exception, is If the user enter '6' in the textbox, then in the worksheet,...` You can use `If Left(textBox1.text,1) <> 6 Then` to check for this condition

Comment: thank you ! I will try this in the morning.

Comment: @SiddharthRout i made the adjustment, I edited my question to add the new code. Can you please take a look? Everything works, just a small detail.

Comment: `When it's only ".6", it doesn't add ".66" like expected` So when the user types 6, you want to show `.66`?

Comment: No I just want to show  `".6"` ! @SiddharthRout I just reread what I wrote, and I wrote it terribly. Sorry english isnt my main langage at all. I edited what I wrote earlier. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you are typing `6` and not `.6` then it should add `.6` to the cell

Comment: @SiddharthRout I just realized I had formating `.00` on. Now I see `0.6` instead of `.60`...

Comment: @SiddharthRout  I made it work ! I updated the code in my question (EDIT 3)

Comment: @chrisneilsen done! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correction to my code that made it work :

```
If Left(TextBox3.Text, 1) <> 6 Then
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C4").NumberFormat = "@"
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C4").Select
    Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
    ActiveCell.Value = "." & Left(TextBox3.Text, 1) & 6
Else
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C4").NumberFormat = "@"
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C4").Select
    Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin
    ActiveCell.Value = ".6"
End If
```